# How to use Nginx to redirect to specific page?

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

Hi am looking to use Nginx to redirect to a certain page for example:
current domain is testing.example.com. The page I wana get to is testing.example.com/test but the domain i wana redirect from is t.example.com so:

t.example.com = testing.example.com/test

Any help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to redirect all the traffic, use this following server block, if you want to concatenate the uri then you could add `$request_uri` in the return statement.

`$scheme` is used to preserve `http` and `https` protocols in the redirected-to location, otherwise you can replace it with either without using `$scheme`

```
server {
    server_name t.example.com;
    location / {
        return 301 $scheme://testing.example.com/test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add in your `t.example.com location { }` something like:

```
rewrite ^(.*) http://testing.example.com/test/$1 permanent;
```

or just simple redirect

```
return 301 http://testing.example.com/test/;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your `server` block of host configuration

```
location /test {
   rewrite ^ $scheme://testing.example.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```